# Compute complement of vector in a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Given an $n$-dimensional vector space $V$ with standard orthonormal basis $\{e_i\}_{i=1,\ldots,n}$. Given $n \times k$ matrix $A = (a_{ij})$ whose column vectors represent the basis of subspace $U \subseteq V$ and $n \times m$ matrix $B = (b_{ij})$ whose columns represent the basis of subspace $W \subseteq U$. How to compute the orthogonal complement of $W$ in $U$ w.r.t. standard scalar product? In particular, I want to find the basis vectors of the orthogonal complement of $W$ in $U$ in terms of a standard basis.

Comment: "The complement" of $W$ in $U$ is not a unique subspace; there are many possible choices. If you have a bilinear form or inner product over $V$, then you can talk about the **orthogonal** complement of $W$

Comment: @BenGrossmann thanks for pointing out, I am interested in orthogonal complement w.r.t. to standard scalar product on $V$.

Comment: There are a few approaches here. Are you trying to do this using pencil or paper or are trying to do this using a computer?

Comment: @BenGrossmann I am doing it with the computer, I use C++ Eigen library for linear algebra algorithms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach. For simplicity, I will take $V = \Bbb R^n$ (or $V = \Bbb C^n$) and $\{e_i\}$ to be the usual (standard) basis, but the same computation works in general.

1. Find a matrix $C$ whose columns are columns of $A$ such that the augmented matrix $[B\ \ C]$ has columns that form a basis of $U$. This can be done by row-reducing (applying Gaussian elimination) to the matrix $[B \ \ A]$ and taking $C$ to be the columns of $A$ corresponding to pivots.
2. Compute a $QR$ decomposition of $[B \ \ C]$. The first $m$ columns of $Q$ form an orthonormal basis of $W \subseteq U$. The remaining $k-m$ columns of $Q$ form an orthonormal basis of the **orthogonal complement of $W$ relative to $U$**.